# Ember doesn't display fetch the models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to do a carousel slider in Ember but I'm already stack since I can't make Ember fetch my images. Here my code:

App:

```
window.ArtRank = Ember.Application.create();

ArtRank.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

Router:

```
ArtRank.Router.map(function (){
        this.resource('index', {path: '/'}, function() {
            this.resource("home", {path: '/'}, function() {
                this.resource("photo", {path: '/photo'});
            });
            this.resource('categories', { path: "/categories" });
            this.resource('profile', { path: "/profile" });
        });
    });


ArtRank.PhotoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('photo');
    }
});
```

Model:

```
ArtRank.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
    imageTitle: DS.attr('string'),
    imageUrl: DS.attr('string')
});

ArtRank.Photo.FIXTURES = [
     {
       id: 1,
       imageTitle: 'Learn Ember.js',
       imageUrl: 'http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg'
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       imageTitle: '...',
       imageUrl: 'http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg'
     },
     {
       id: 3,
       imageTtitle: 'Profit!',
       imageUrl: 'http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg'
     }
];
```

My Templates are made by:
Index within header and footer and {{outlet}}

Outelet call home.hbs that is: {{partial photo}}

home.hbs render photo.hbs that is:

```
<div class="photos-wrap">
        <h1>{{ imageTitle }}</h1>

        <div class="photoItem">
                <img id="photoItem" {{bind-attr src="imageUrl"}} />
        </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For answer to my own question (so it doesn't stay open), it works every things fine, I just didn't understand that you need to go in the specific router for fetch that datas. I thought that you can fetch them from everywhere in the app but of' course just display when you are in the specific application.

Answer (score 0):

You missed an each in your template because the result of the model hook of your reoute definition is an array

```
  {{#each}}
    <h1>{{ imageTitle }}</h1>

    <div class="photoItem">
            <img id="photoItem" {{bind-attr src="imageUrl"}} />
    </div>
  {{/each}}
```

Also the resource definition is not correct IMHO two / paths... try a config like

```
    this.resource('index', {path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource("home", {path: 'home'}, function() {
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, is a good point but unfortunately that's not the problem since looking with the Ember inspector I don't get the dates at all. My ArtRankPhoto is empty :(

Comment: Try changing the resource definition :-)